# Macbook pro Mid-2012 camera not working

Tags: macbook-pro, camera

Recently replaced HDD to SSD. After replacing it the camera stopped working - green light not showing up. When opening the FaceTime app I only see a black screen.

Comment: The iSight (webcam) cable and DC in board are on opposite sides of the MBP from each other and both are opposite the hard drive.  I would check each item individually.  Start with the power adapter.  Make sure it still works.  I’m assuming the computer boots as you said the iSight camera no longer works. Check to see that you didn’t disconnect the cable

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS that you are running? Have you restored the installation from your previous hard disk or performed a fresh installation of macOS?

Answer (score -1):

I would check the webcam connection first maybe even disconnect and reconnect. If you can't do this, a local IT guy or apple store might do it. Google it to find what it looks like.